# How to add admob ads into the app?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, admob, surfaceview

I have SurfaceView where I draw some sketches. But I don't use xml layout...
Am I abble to add AdView into SurfaceView in Java Android? Is it possible?

For example, in ActionScript it will be like that:
surfaceView.addChild(adView);

Is there something similar in java?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://rx-games.com/admob-adverts-on-surfaceview-no-xml-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

this lib is free and easy to use
http://lilili87222.github.com/admob-for-flash/

user can show all type of banner ad and full screen(interstitial advertising) ad of admob

user can show landscope and portrait advertising in actionscript 3 mobile application

user can set postion of ad

easy to use